# Why is this environment giving me trouble? (enumitem package)

Tags: environments, enumitem

the next environment definition is giving me some trouble:
`\newenvironment{properties}{\textbf{\underline{Properties:}}\begin{enumerate}[style=(P_{\arabic*}]}{\end{enumerate}}`

When I try to use it, I get the next errors:

- `! Missing number, treated as zero.<to be read again>\c@*l.7  ts:}}\begin{enumerate}[style=(P_{\arabic* }]`
- `! Missing \endcsname inserted.<to be read again>\c@*l.7 ...ts:}}\begin{enumerate}[style=(P_{\arabic*}]`
- `! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.<argument> enit@style@(P_{\arabic *}`
- `! Extra \endcsname.\@ifundefined ...dafter \ifx \csname #1\endcsname\relax \expandafter \@firs... ...ts:}}\begin{enumerate}[style=(P_{\arabic}]`
- `! Missing number, treated as zero.<to be read again>\c@*l.7 ...ts:}}\begin{enumerate}[style=(P_{\arabic*}]`

Can you help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? Thank you :).

Comment: Without a MWE, my guess is that you want to use `\newlist` and `\setlist` instead of `\newenvironment`, as in section 7 of [enumitem's documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf).

Comment: What do you mean with MWE? And yes, I want to create a custom list but I also want to add a title to it (_Properties_ in fact).

Comment: `style` is not the right key; shouldn't it be `label=($P_{\arabic*}$)`?

Comment: @egreg nvm my last comment. It's working fine now. Thanks a lot! (PS: I'm dumb lolz. Thank you again :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several errors:

1. Underlining should never be used in good typography
2. `style` is not the right key
3. You miss math mode around the subscript

So a guess could be

```
\newenvironment{properties}
  {\textbf{Properties:}\begin{enumerate}[label=(P$_{\arabic*}$)]}
  {\end{enumerate}}
```

A better guess:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment{properties}
  {\par\vspace{\topsep}
   \noindent\textbf{Properties:}
   \begin{enumerate}[label=(P$_{\arabic*}$)]}
  {\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}

\begin{properties}
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\end{properties}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

May be use `enumitem` capabilities

```
\newlist{properties}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[properties]{before=\endgraf\vspace{\topsep}\noindent\textbf{Properties:},
                     label=(P$_{\arabic*}$)}
```